# svnsync fails with "E175002: REPORT request on '/<root>/!svn/rev/71' failed"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've tried this so many times that I wrote this brain-dead Windows batch file:

```
if %1x == x goto :EOF

set BACKUP_REPO=%1
set SOURCE_REPO=<url>

svnadmin create %BACKUP_REPO%
echo exit 0 > %BACKUP_REPO%\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
svnsync init file:///%BACKUP_REPO% %SOURCE_REPO%
svnsync sync file:///%BACKUP_REPO%
```

The operation proceeds without problems until it gets to revision 71, at which point it fails with the above error. I've looked at all the related answers I could find, but none of them address my specific problem, as they don't involve svnsync.

```
PS E:\svn> .\create_backup.bat E:\svn\backuprepo3
E:\svn>if E:\svn\backuprepo3x == x goto :EOF
E:\svn>set BACKUP_REPO=E:\svn\backuprepo3
E:\svn>set SOURCE_REPO=<url>
E:\svn>svnadmin create E:\svn\backuprepo3
E:\svn>echo exit 0  1>E:\svn\backuprepo3\hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat
E:\svn>svnsync init file:///E:\svn\backuprepo3 <url>
Copied properties for revision 0.
E:\svn>svnsync sync file:///E:\svn\backuprepo3
Committed revision 1.
Copied properties for revision 1.
Committed revision 2.
Copied properties for revision 2.
Committed revision 3.
Copied properties for revision 3.
Transmitting file data ...............................................................................................................................................................................
<snip>
Committed revision 68.
Copied properties for revision 68.
Committed revision 69.
Copied properties for revision 69.
Transmitting file data ...............
Committed revision 70.
Copied properties for revision 70.
svnsync: E175002: REPORT request on '/<root>/!svn/rev/71' failed
PS E:\svn>
```

I'd be okay with losing the first 70 revisions (the repo is up to rev. 1265 or so), but I have no idea how to get past this point.

The master is on a CollabNet CloudForge account, so I have no visibility into the server side - not even SVN version. I can view revs 69 through 72 using the repo browser without detecting any problems.

The client is TortoiseSVN (command line utilities):
PS E:\svn> svnsync --version
svnsync, version 1.11.0 (r1845130)
   compiled Oct 30 2018, 21:50:05 on x86-microsoft-windows

How do I go about analyzing this problem? Are there diagnostic tools? Log files? Guys who just know the answer?

Thanks,

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just got the same error and the solution was simple: **Run the `svnsync sync` command again.** It succeeded the second time for me.